# Who should I get LOR from : manager of big prestigious company where I worked 5 years back, or unknown small company where I worked recently?

Tags: masters, application, recommendation-letter

I am applying for MS in CS. 6+ years of work experience.

I worked for a huge, globally well known company for less than a year straight out school. This was 5 years back.

I also worked for a very small unknown company for about 3 years.

I can get letters from both, and the content of both will be about the same I think.

Which one should I use for applications? I already have 1 from my professor with whom I did research, and another from my last company where I worked. I just need to submit a 3rd one.

Answer (score 2):

The badge, of whatever worth, for having worked in a "globally well-known" company is already in your cv.

And, it is just "few months work straight out of school", begging the question "coffee anyone?" (only half-jokingly).

But chances are, in the "very small unknown company", your role was much more *critical*, compared. And it was for three whole years.

If I was the reader, it would be this second letter that would be more believable in my eyes if it mentioned anything about efficiency, professionalism, and dependability.

Answer (score -1):

If only one manager has a graduate degree, use that one. If one went to a higher ranked university, use that one. If neither one has a graduate degree, or both have equally ranked degrees, use the one with the higher ranked undergraduate degree.

If you don't know and feel uncomfortable asking for this information, you could use the more senior or more experienced manager.